# (Seemingly) random freezes and I can't use Magic Sys Req

Tags: kernel, freeze

Across multiple installations of Ubuntu or Kubuntu and multiple versiones of Linux kernel, my laptop randomly freezes and it won't unfreeze with time, nor the Magic Sys Req works, so I think it's a kernel issue.
Nothing works when the laptop freezes in such way: mouse, keyboard, trackpad, the sensor that checks if I close the laptop. The only thing I can do is shut down the laptop with the power button.

### Laptop info

Lenovo Ideapad B51-30
OS: Kubuntu 20.04 - 64-bit
Kernel versione: 5.4.0-58-generic

Sysrq ARE enabled: I can normally use them while the system is not frozen in the way I'm reporting.

### Logs

So I collected some `kern.log` reporting what, I think, happened just before the freeze. Seeing that they are not coherent, I fear that my issue is not reported in the logs. But if you have any advice of which log I could check everytime a freeze happens, I'll collect it too.

#### /var/log/kern.log

I saved the last line of the logs everytime the laptop froze. I skipped the very last lines, those which refers to the booting of the pc.
You can read them here https://nextcloud.samuelezappala.it/s/pkLJiLEk5oo5fDQ

### Memory Test

I made a memtest and it found no error, at least for the 5 hours it run.

## EDIT 1

Could it be related with some issue with the hard disk? I also always had problems with long boot time, and that's what I usualli find in the `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
└─home.mount @18.818s +142ms
  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c265799a\x2d64c9\x2d4290\x2d86d4\x2d7951bb12ebf3.service @17.229s +1.530s
    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-c265799a\x2d64c9\x2d4290\x2d86d4\x2d7951bb12ebf3.device @17.226s
```

Meanwhile I'm looking for a way to inspect my motherboard.

Comment: Is mouse at least working?

Comment: Have you confirmed you don't have a hardware issue?  ie. if you boot & run a *live* system (ideally something different) is the machine stable?  have you run memory tests? inspected motherboard? psu? etc

Comment: Nothing is working: mouse, keyboard, trackpad. Only the screen stays on on the last image it printed. The only think I can do is shut it down with the power button.

Comment: What do you mean by running a *live* system? Using Ubuntu on a USB stick? I'll try, but generally is stable and it never froze in such state (but maybe because I used the live os for very short time). I'll look for how to do a memory test or inspect my motherboard, or what a psu is.

Comment: It is: I can reboot anytime doing Alt+Stamp+B, but not while the system is frozen in this way.

Comment: I just updates with my memtest, that didn't give me nothing.